# How to print current loop number in an iteration over a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension, python-2.7

I have a dictionary

```
>>>d = {"a":"apple", "c":"cat", "d":"dog"}
```

That dictionary should be printed to output in this particular format:

```
1. apple
2. cat
3. dog
```

If I *have* to use list comprehension to do so,
how would I go about getting it to also print the current iteration number i.e. 1 or 2 or 3 as per above output.

This is what I have so far and it just prints the dict values on newlines, but it is far from what I want.

```
>>>temp =  "\n".join( [d[i] for i in d] )
>>>print temp
```

- Also, is it beneficial to use a generator instead of list comprehension here?
- Enviroment: Python 2.7

Comment: I don't really want to give the whole answer since it looks like a homework, But that might help http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: do they have to be in alphabetical order?

Comment: @wim No not necessatily.

Comment: @yilmazhuseyin Its not exactly my homework, its an oversimplfiication of a problem Im having interpreting pickled data sent over the network and part of my receiver function, which I cannot modify, has only one string argument it can take where it expects to see a string formatted like the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorted by value:

```
print '\n'.join('{}. {}'.format(i, d[k]) for (i,k) in enumerate(sorted(d, key=d.get), 1))
1. apple
2. cat
3. dog
```

---

Sorted by key:

```
>>> print '\n'.join('{}. {}'.format(i, d[k]) for (i,k) in enumerate(sorted(d), 1))
1. apple
2. cat
3. dog
```

---

Unsorted (results will come out however `dict` feels like giving them)

```
>>> print '\n'.join('{}. {}'.format(i, v) for (i,v) in enumerate(d.itervalues(), 1))
1. apple
2. cat
3. dog
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what Im looking for, although it doesnt need to be sorted really. Question: Does 'i' get initialised to 0 automatically?

Comment: I was gonna use a generator anyway, so its all good there. Thanks a ton.

Comment: `enumerate` counts from 0, so yes.

Comment: Oh I got it, so enumerate returns a tuple of the number and value. Perfect, thanks again.

Comment: Set second argument of enumerate() to 1 to start counting from 1.

Comment: I would sort by key by `enumerate`ing the `.iteritems` with a key that applies `operator.itemgetter` to the resulting list of 2-tuples. To sort by value, since we're displaying the values, we can just apply `sorted` to the `.itervalues` used in the third example.

Answer (score 4):

```
In [90]: for i,arr in enumerate(d.values(), 1):
   ....:     print i, arr
   ....:     
   ....:     

1 apple
2 cat
3 dog
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple dictionary iteration code will do this. See the string formatting as well to pint out the location exactly as requested.

```
d = {"a":"apple", "c":"cat", "d":"dog"}

count=1
for k,v in d.iteritems():
   print "%s. %s" % (count, k)
   count +=1
```